# Game Theory against One Random and One Intelligent Player

Tags: probability, game-theory

You are playing a game with two other players. You all get a chance to select a random integer from 1-100 (inclusive) and the player with the lowest number is paid that amount by both of the other players. In the case of a tie for the lowest number, no payment is made. One of the players you play against randomly selects a number from 1-100. The other is intelligent and will play optimally. What would be the best strategy?

For a simplified case, in which you played against only the random player, I calculated that the optimal choice was 33 or 34, in which your expected winnings were 16.83. However, for the three-person game, I am not sure what the strategy would be. I feel like you and the other intelligent player will constantly try to undercut each other, but I don't feel like the equilibrium should be 1 because there is money to be made by taking advantage of the random player.

Comment: Do you have to pick an integer amount?

Comment: Yes, thanks, edited the question.

Comment: For both the nonrandom players to choose $1$ is a stable equilibrium though (ie any of them loses money if they change strategies).

Comment: I completely agree with the other responses and wish to point out the great mathematical advantage that *collusion* would be in this situation.  This is why, in the business world, collusion is so attractive.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pick $1$ always. This strategy dominates every other strategy.

If the optimal guy plays $1$ everytime, then you *will* lose money unless you also play $1$ everytime.

The uniform random guy is the real winner here, because in this equilibrium he'll never need to pay over money!

Comment: I agree that in equilibrium the two intelligent players will play 1. There are a lot of games where the equilibrium is not the best outcome in terms of welfare. Check the prisoners dilemma. However, in this game the random guy is not a winner. In expectation he pays some money to the other two. The intelligent players pay 1 to each other (cancels out) and get something from the random guy (unless he plays 1). They could maximize their expected income by agreeing to play the 1 vs 1-optimal strategy but this is not an equilibrium.